# how can send badge from firebase-admin to android application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-admin, badge

I want to send badge from firebase-admin to applications.
I can send badge to iOS apps and show its on app icon but in android can not.
how can send badge from firebase-admin to android applications and show its on app icon?

Answer (score 1):

App badge appears on application icons when notification as pending. So, To display a badge on the app icon you have to send notification using firebase.

But for android, the badge supports above android 8.0 (API level 26). You can check the [official](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges) document for that.

If you want to implement for all android versions then you can get the help of custom libraries like [this one](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger).

Comment: use ShortcutBadger but when my app is closed android version <8 can not get and show badge from server in react native.

Comment: Make sure you have implement service for badge. here it is https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/me/leolin/shortcutbadger/example/BadgeIntentService.java

Comment: I use react native framework to develop my apps. how can use this service in react native?